# Removing strings from a list of strings and ints python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list such as `['A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3]`

I want a function so that I can remove the strings from my list and make it only have integers? There are always alternating strings and integers in the list if that helps.

Comment: `my_list[1::2]`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop through your list and only keep the elements with type integer:

```
original_list = ['A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3]

[n for n in original_list if type(n) is int]
```

Which outputs

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to wrap it to a function you can use this:

```
def remove_all_but_int(my_list):
    my_list = [n for n in my_list if type(n) is int]
    return (my_list)
```

new_list = remove_all_but_int(original_list)

Which gives you the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3]
b = [x for x in a if isinstance(x, int)]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you simply want to remove every second item you should do this:
The modulo `%` gets the remainder after dividing.

```
count = 0
for c in lista: # iterate the list
    if count % 2 == 0: # every second iteration
        lista.remove(c) # remove
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
a=['A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3]
for i in a:
    if i.isalpha():
        a.remove(i)
print (a)
```

2.

```
a=['A', 12, 'B', 2, 'C', 3]
b=[x for x in a if type(x) is int]
print (b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more option - use of [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
orig = ['A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3]
res = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), orig))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution :

```
list_1=['A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3]



print([i for i in list_1 if not isinstance(i,str)])
```

if you are having trouble with understanding above syntax here is detailed solution :

```
new_list=[]

for i in list_1:
    if not isinstance(i,str):
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```